# External page in iframe

Tags: apex, visualforce, iframe

I need to display the external page in VF page iframe

But I'm getting **[www.salesforce.com](http://www.salesforce.com) refused to connect.**

I added salesforce in CORS and csp sites
Below is my code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:iframe src="https://www.salesforce.com" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to frame a page depends on the page's [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header. Salesforce doesn't allow framing as a security feature. You'll want to test with a page that allows being framed (the default if X-Frame-Options is not specified, or allowed by domain. As a side note, CORS settings do not affect frames, only JavaScript's ability to access cross-domain servers.